# Joomla site Browser title will not change

Tags: joomla

I have cloned a website into a different domain and I am trying to change the browser title that shows up in the website tab. I have changed the page display Browser Page Title on the home page module(which was blank), I have changed the page title, its still showing the same title that was on the old website. I could change something in the code but Im not sure where to find it. Is there another place where this title can be changed from on the menu or code?

```
    <?php
    /**
    * @package    Joomla.Site
    *
    * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All    rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

/**
 * Define the application's minimum supported PHP version as a constant so it can be referenced within the application.
 */
define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '5.3.10');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP, '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP ' . JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP . ' or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

// Saves the start time and memory usage.
$startTime = microtime(1);
$startMem  = memory_get_usage();

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Execute the application.
$app->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Log into joomla and navigate to `admin area > Menus > Main Menu > Home > Parameters - System > Page Title`. There you should see an option to change `Browser Page Title`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am seeing index.php but not sure where index,html is located, is there a way to quickly find it on file manager.

Comment: @FransB index.php is basically the equivalent of index.html, the `<title>` should be near the top.

Comment: I am not finding the title tag on index.php, there is only a few lines of code in that file

Comment: @FransB, why don't you add the index.php file to the question so I can take a look

Comment: @FransB I just did some extra research, try that

Comment: what is it that Im supposed to try? I have already changed the Browser page title and that doesn't work, ir are you talking about something else