# How Change Title tags on joomla browser title

Tags: joomla

I have cloned a website into a different domain and I am trying to change the browser title that shows up in the website tab. I have changed the page display Browser Page Title on the home page module(which was blank), I have changed the page title, its still showing the same title that was on the old website. Where can I go into the code and change the title tags myself? which file changes this?

Comment: You have already asked this question and are receiving help at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41400860/1983389. Please don't ask the same question twice as it wastes peoples time.

Comment: the answer I got was completly useless, I thought rephrasing the question could help ppl understand better and help other ppl with same problem

Comment: does nobody know where the title tags for joomla are on the code? I never used joomla before so cits hard for me but it seems like someone with some joomla experience could explain this easily

Comment: It is best to edit the original question rather than post the same question again. If the answer provided is useless, explain why to elicit better answers.

Comment: I did but got no response

Comment: Maybe try posting the question to http://joomla.stackexchange.com which is a more appropriate place to post this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page you are concerned about is also linked to a menu item, from the back end go to
**Menus > Your Menu > Your Menu Item**

Then open the **Page Display tab** and check the entry for **Browser Page Title**

If this still doesn't solve your problem, check that the page title isn't coming from an SEO extension like [sh404SEF](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef)

Good luck

Comment: I solved is it was a plugin was over riding the page titles, but It was hard to find because im new to joomla